# jQuery apply onmouseover event attribute to tr, works in Firefox but in no other browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, onmouseover

I want a certain Javascript function to be called when the user mouse-overs / mouse-outs or clicks on all table rows (tr) with an id beginning with 'pos_'. I want to apply this from Javascript in order to reduce the size of the original HTML sent from the web server.

The following experiment with `onmouseover` works in Firefox, but in none of Google Chrome, MSIE 8, Safari or Opera:

```
var x = $('tr[id^=\'row_\']');
alert(x);
$(x).attr('onmouseover', 'alert("aaa");');
$('td:eq(1)',$(x)).addClass('result');
```

In all 5 browsers the 3 lines except the one with `onmouseover` works.
The line with `onmouseover` only works in Firefox.

The javascript I was planning on executing instead of the alert, once it works, is something like

```
myMouseOver(this);
```

in order to perform some javascript work based on the row data contents when the mouse is hovering over it. (No, the work cannot be done only using CSS).

How do I apply an onmouseover event so it works in several of the relevant browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `mouseover` function in jQuery, instead of setting the `onmouseover` attribute. See the API [here](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).

Comment: Indeed. It seems to work in all browsers except Opera but I can live with that. Thanks.